# What's the accepted way to render arbitrarily nested objects in a template in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I'm returning an object embedding other objects to arbitrary depth (representing a directory tree) from a template helper, and I'd like to render it into my template as a nested list. Since the philosophy of spacebars is to keep logic out of the template, all it offers is for loops and if statements. This is fine for iterating over most objects and arrays, even ones nested to a known depth, but for arbitrarily deep objects it's not sufficient. I've come up with a few different possible strategies, none of which I feel are particularly clean:

- In the template helper, instead return a flattened depth-first list of directories, each tagged with a depth. Then, using some ugly logic in the template, I could create and close li tags based on the depth of the next directory. Yuck.
- I could have my template helper build the HTML from the data and return it to the template to be displayed, committing the other cardinal sin of having presentational stuff in my template helper.
- Concede that, in reality, my UI will have to have some limit to the depth of folders it shows at one time, and just use nested for loops in my template. This would result in 4-5 ugly nested for loops, and an inflexible design.
- Skip the template helper altogether and manually manipulate the dom with jquery, wrapping it all in Deps.Autorun to maintain reactivity. This would probably require some hackyness to emulate the way blaze keeps the dom in sync with the data.

I must be overlooking something here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use a recursive template?

```
<template name="tree">
  {{value}}

  <ul>
    {{#each children}}
      <li>{{> tree}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="container">
  {{> tree treeData}}
</template>

Template.container.helpers({
  treeData: function () {
    return {
      value: "level 1",
      children: [
        { value: "level 2" },
        { value: "level 2" },
        { value: "level 2" }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I had no idea recursive templates were possible. This is perfect, thank you!